# Is it possible in MSW (mock service worker) to passthrough unhandled requests but inspect requests and responses?

Tags: javascript, handler, msw

Using MSW wrapped around AUT to do the mocking.

I want to be able to 'see' the responses for unhandled requests which I currently passthrough.

Cant do it using the onUnhandledRequest (`res.passthrough()`) as this is just telling MSW that you want to 'pass through'.

I thought about using a 'default' handler, that would forward the request on to the required destination, then inspect the response (Actually to write details to a file for future test inspection) before passing back to the AUT as its response.

However, I can't work out how to do a 'default' handler (IE. If request is not matched to any of the handlers list then process with 'this'...)?

Answer (score 1):

I actually got the answer from the MSW guys.  I'm putting it in here incase others need it (Many thanks to Artem Zakharchenko);

First things first, the onUnhandledRequest function is not intended to affect the traffic in any way. This extends to its inability to observe the actual response because it's out of its intended scope. You shouldn't be using this function for anything but to tell MSW how to react to unhandled requests: throw an error, warn you, or do nothing. Think of it as a logger customization function that lives outside of the request resolution algorithm (that's precisely what it is).

You may try using `rest.all('*')` for your use case but bear in mind that you don't have access to the original response instance there. You can, however, perform the request as-is within the handler and inspect that proxy response.

```
rest.all('*', async (req, res, ctx) => {
  const proxyResponse = await ctx.fetch(req)
  console.log({ req, proxyResponse })
})
```

Note that I don't recommend this method because it affects the outgoing traffic. This makes another request while processing an existing one, and it's not what you want to achieve.

## Solution

However, what I would recommend is using the Life-cycle API. It's designed specifically for network monitoring and it has two designated methods for observing responses:

```
response:bypass

response:mocked
```

Use the `response:bypass` event to react to any response your application receives that wasn't handled by your request handlers:

```
worker.events.on('response:bypass', (response, requestId) => {
  console.log('%d %s', response.status, response.statusText)
})
```

You get the requestId argument in that listener, which is a UUID pointing to the original request behind this response. You can associate requests and responses by listening to request:* events and storing requests by their IDs. In your case, listening to the request:unhandled event makes more sense.

Comment: @matwalker As a note: accepting this as an answer is also helpful for the question :-)